# Escrever arquivo em .ASP com condições JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, asp

Como eu faço para escrever um arquivo .ASP se uma condição em JAVASCRIPT?

OBS: EU já consigo escrever arquivos em .ASP tranquilo.

Abaixo o pedaço do fonte como exemplo:

```
<script>

if(1 == 2) { // ISSO É FALSO, PORTANTE ELE DEVE IR PARA O ELSE, POREM ELE FAZ TODO ASP 
    <% 
     oStream.WriteLine "ESCREVE LINHA 2" 

    If (1 = 1) Then 'IF DO ASP, SE 1 = 2, ELE NÃO ESCREVE , ESTÁ OK
        oStream.WriteLine "ESCREVE LINHA 3"

    End If
    %>

} else {
    <% oStream.WriteLine "ESCREVE FIM" %>
}
```

Então, quando a condição do javascript for falso, ele não respeita, e faz todo ASP.

O resultado do meu arquivo é:

...

ESCREVE LINHA 2 //ESSA NAO DEVERIA TER

ESCREVE LINHA 3 // NEM ESSA

ESCREVE FIM
...

Eu tentei color o fonte inteiro pra você testarem, mais não consigo, da um bug no editor.

Fonte real:

```
if (frm['MAPA'].window.ChecarDentroDoPonto('VEICULOS', '{<%=rs("VeiculoID")%>-<%=rsPosicao("VeiculoLogID")%>}', '{<%=strChaveRotaP%>}') == false) {
    document.write('<input type="hidden" name="SQL" value="UPDATE VeiculosLogsAuxiliar SET RotaP=\'A\' WHERE PrefixoView=\'<%=rs("PrefixoView")%>\' AND VeiculoLogID=<%=rsPosicao("VeiculoLogID")%>">');

    <% If IsNull(strEmailNew) = False Then
        If InStr(1, strEmailNew, "@") > 0 Then %>

            document.write('<input type="hidden" name="AlertaEmailVeiculoID" value="<%=rs("VeiculoID")%>">');
            document.write('<input type="hidden" name="AlertaEmailAlerta" value="ROTAP<%=lngRotaPID%>-<%=lngPontoIDAtual%>">');
            document.write('<input type="hidden" name="AlertaEmailEmail" value="<%=strEmailNew%>">');
            document.write('<input type="hidden" name="AlertaEmailTitulo" value="<%=strEmpresa & " - ALERTA - " & rsPosicao("DtLog")%>">');
            document.write('<input type="hidden" name="AlertaEmailMensagem" value="<%="Cliente: " & rs("NomeFantasia") & "<br>" & "Veículo: " & rs("VeiculoID") & " - " & rs("Placa") & " - " & rs("Descricao") & "<br>" & "Atrasado na rota \'" & strRotaPDescricao & "\'" %>">');

        <%
        End If
    End If
    %>

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

## O Problema:

```
<script>
if(1==2)
{
alert('entrou na condicao 1');
<%
Response.Write("ASP: condicao01")
%>
}
else
{
alert('entrou na condicao 2');
<%
Response.Write("ASP: condicao02")
%>
}
</script>
```

Em teoria o que acha que irá aparecer na tela?
a resposta é um erro de javascript e quem sabe um alert2

a saida ser algo assim

```
<script>
if(1==2)
{
alert('entrou na condicao 1');
ASP: condicao01
}
else
{
alert('entrou na condicao 2');
ASP: condicao02
}
</script>
```

## Porque?

Porque primeiro o ASP é processado no servidor, e escrito o html dele. depois enviado para o browser e ai o javascript é executado pelo navegador...ou seja o ASP já foi processado antes...

Você deve fazer a mesma validação no ASP
ou de preferencia fazer o contrário

```
<%
if 1 = 1 then
   <script>
        //colocar o script javascript aqui
   </script>
else
   <script>
        //colocar o script javascript aqui
   </script>
end if
%>
```

assim o servidor processa e só envia um ou outro script de javascript...tenta postar o código inteiro assim posso dar a solução, aqui passei somente a lógica e o porque.

Caso realmente tenha que validar primeiro em js, chame uma page externa que grave o log. algo do tipo:

```
 <script>
    if(1==2)
    {
       $("#idElemento").load('gravaLog.asp?formato=1');
    }
    else
    {
       $("#idElemento").load('gravaLog.asp?formato=2');
    }
    </script>
```

você também pode chamar paginas diferentes, etc, etc. Assim irá funcionar.

Comment: entendi, mas tenho que fazer a condição em JS mesmo, pois estou fazendo um integração com o google MAPS, ai preciso desenhar no mapa um veiculo (em JS), e verificar em (JS) se o desenho esta dentro do ponto, vou tentar postar uma parte do codigo:

Comment: postei: FONTE REAL, editei a duvida

Comment: humm então faz o seguinte..
if(1=1)
{
$("#idElemento").load('gravaLog01.asp');
}
else
{
$("#idElemento").load('gravalog02.asp');
}

Comment: no fonte real eu quero substituir os document.write por oStream.WriteLine em ASP

Comment: editei a resposta original

Comment: entendi, obrigado. Mas acho que vou fazer usando ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"), ai escrevo em JS mesmo, O que você acha dessa solução? Tipo, vai funcionar so no IE, mas como eh um monitor interno, nao tem problema.

Comment: Excelente resposta, bem explicativa, parabéns.

Comment: vandrebr1 não esqueça de marcar como resposta